# New column of number values corresponding to an existing single column in R

Tags: r

My df:

```
df$ADF(DEATH, DEATH, ALIVE, ALIVE, UNSURE NOW, DEATH)
```

I would like to get df:

```
df$ADF(DEATH, DEATH, ALIVE, ALIVE, UNSURE NOW, DEATH)
df$OUT(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0)
```

my current code is:

```
df %>% mutate(OUT = if else(ADF == "DEATH" ~ 0, ADF == "ALIVE" ~ 1, ADF == "UNSURE NOW" ~1))
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of multiple conditions, this can be done with a single expression on 'ADF' with `!=` on 'DEATH' to return logical vector and then coerce it to binary (`+` or `as.integer`)

```
df$OUT <-  +(df$ADF != 'DEATH')
```

-output

```
df
#         ADF OUT
#1      DEATH   0
#2      DEATH   0
#3      ALIVE   1
#4      ALIVE   1
#5 UNSURE NOW   1
#6      DEATH   0
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(ADF = c('DEATH', 'DEATH', 'ALIVE', 'ALIVE',
         'UNSURE NOW', 'DEATH'))
```